# WinSCP and "(ESkipFile)" in the transfer log / file exluded from transfer

Tags: winscp

I've been trying to simply upload files using WinSCP scripting and am continually getting this in the logs:

```
. 2023-03-21 13:53:11.756 File "whatever.zip" excluded from transfer
* 2023-03-21 13:53:11.756 (ESkipFile)
```

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to ensure you have no file masks enabled in the GUI.  You can see what masks you have enabled in the transfer log file in this line:

```
. 2023-03-21 13:53:11.756   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: *.new; ResumeL: 0
```

Specifically, note the **'InclM:*.new;'** part of the text.  That means (in my case), I had the file mask "*.new" applied, which caused everything that wasn't named with the extension ".new" to be skipped.

I had to open the GUI, Options -> Preferences -> Transfer tree and edit each Preset that had the mask applied by clicking the 'Edit' button.  On the 'Edit transfer settings preset' dialog box, I had to go to the 'Other' section at the bottom of the dialog box, click the 'Edit' button, then the 'Clear' button to clear out the masks in the 'Include files:' list, the 'Ok' out of the boxes.

Another (and likely better) option (per Martin Prikryl's comment) is to add /ini=nul to the WinSCP command line, so the GUI settings are ignored for scripting purposes.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well, the correct approach is not to configure the WinSCP GUI. That will only bite you later, once you change the GUI configuration again for whatever reason. The correct approach is to isolate the script from the GUI configuration by adding `/ini=nul` commandline switch. See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#configuration

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I really just wanted to get something posted somewhere about this issue, so the search engines could index it.  I couldn't find much of anything out there.